# How to achieve the following using functions/stored procedure in SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-function

I have the following table with following data as

```
                                            Tab1
FutureMISBoundaryVersion  CurrentMISBoundaryVersion  FutureHAMBoundaryVersion  CurrentHAMBoundaryVersion 
2:21,5:50,4:55,7:80,9:33  2:12,5:40,4:35,7:60,9:87   2:52,5:90,4:75,7:30,9:57  2:42,5:60,4:95,7:70,9:37
```

This key value pair has to be split into and the value of each key has to be inserted into another table in the following fashion

```
FutureMIS-OAKVersion |FutureMIS-HAMVersion |FutureMIS-DURVersion | FutureMIS-BURVersion| FutureMIS-YRTVersion |DeviceMIS-OAKVersion|DeviceMIS-HAMVersion |DeviceMIS-DURVersion| DeviceMIS-BURVersion| DeviceMIS-YRTVersion
              33     |              80     |            21       |            55       |  50                  | 87                 |  60                 |12                  |35                   | 40
```

i,e: when it finds column 'FutureMISBoundaryVersion' in tab1 then its value 
'2:21,5:50,4:55,7:80,9:33' will be split and its value is inserted in such a way that the corresponding value of key 2 i,e:21 will be inserted into FutureMIS-DURVersion column.

Similarly key 5's value 50 will be inserted into FutureMIS-BURVersion column and so on for other keys

when it finds column 'CurrentMISBoundaryVersion' then
'2:12,5:40,4:35,7:60,9:87' will be split and its value is inserted in such a way that the corresponding value of key 2 i,e:12 will be inserted into CurrentMIS-DURVersion column similarly key 5's 40 value will be inserted into DeviceMIS-YRTVersion column and so on for other columns of the source table.

The table structure may extend as I have shown only 4 source table column  but logic for all the columns remain same

Comment: Are the lengths of all the values the same in each column?

Comment: No, it varies @ Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very funky requirements to be honest.
Please note solution below will work only in SQL Server 2016+ as I'm using JSON to parse the data. However you can write your own parser, in this case code will work in almost all versions of SQL Server.

**Parse function:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ParseIt(@Type NVARCHAR(255),@Value NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS @Parsed TABLE (Code NVARCHAR(255),Value NVARCHAR(255))
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Parsed(Code,Value)
    SELECT @Type + '-' + m.Code + 'Version' AS [Code],p.[1] AS [Value]
    FROM (
        SELECT j.[key] AS [ID],i.[key],i.value
        FROM OPENJSON('["' + REPLACE(@Value,',','","') + '"]') j
        CROSS APPLY OPENJSON('[' + REPLACE(j.[value],':',',') + ']') i
    ) a
    PIVOT(MAX(a.value) FOR a.[key] IN ([0],[1])) p
    INNER JOIN ( VALUES
        (2,'DUR')
        ,(4,'BUR')
        ,(5,'YRT')
        ,(7,'HAM')
        ,(9,'OAK')
    ) m(ID, Code) ON m.ID = p.[0]
    ;
    RETURN;
END
```

**Initial data:**

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (FutureMISBoundaryVersion NVARCHAR(MAX), CurrentMISBoundaryVersion NVARCHAR(MAX),FutureHAMBoundaryVersion NVARCHAR(MAX),CurrentHAMBoundaryVersion NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @Table(FutureMISBoundaryVersion,CurrentMISBoundaryVersion,FutureHAMBoundaryVersion,CurrentHAMBoundaryVersion)VALUES
    ('2:21,5:50,4:55,7:80,9:33','2:12,5:40,4:35,7:60,9:87','2:52,5:90,4:75,7:30,9:57','2:42,5:60,4:95,7:70,9:37')
;
```

**The code:**

```
SELECT COALESCE(p.[FutureMIS-OAKVersion],'') AS [FutureMIS-OAKVersion]
    ,COALESCE(p.[FutureMIS-HAMVersion],'') AS [FutureMIS-HAMVersion]
    ,COALESCE(p.[FutureMIS-DURVersion],'') AS [FutureMIS-DURVersion]
    ,COALESCE(p.[FutureMIS-BURVersion],'') AS [FutureMIS-BURVersion]
    ,COALESCE(p.[FutureMIS-YRTVersion],'') AS [FutureMIS-YRTVersion]
    ,COALESCE(p.[DeviceMIS-OAKVersion],'') AS [DeviceMIS-OAKVersion]
    ,COALESCE(p.[DeviceMIS-HAMVersion],'') AS [DeviceMIS-HAMVersion]
    ,COALESCE(p.[DeviceMIS-DURVersion],'') AS [DeviceMIS-DURVersion]
    ,COALESCE(p.[DeviceMIS-BURVersion],'') AS [DeviceMIS-BURVersion]
    ,COALESCE(p.[DeviceMIS-YRTVersion],'') AS [DeviceMIS-YRTVersion]
FROM (
    SELECT f.Code,f.Value FROM @Table t CROSS APPLY dbo.ParseIt('FutureMIS',t.FutureMISBoundaryVersion) f
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT f.Code,f.Value FROM @Table t CROSS APPLY dbo.ParseIt('DeviceMIS',t.CurrentMISBoundaryVersion) f
) a
PIVOT(MAX(a.Value) FOR a.Code IN ([DeviceMIS-BURVersion],[DeviceMIS-DURVersion],[DeviceMIS-HAMVersion],[DeviceMIS-OAKVersion]
    ,[DeviceMIS-YRTVersion],[FutureMIS-BURVersion],[FutureMIS-DURVersion],[FutureMIS-HAMVersion],[FutureMIS-OAKVersion]
    ,[FutureMIS-YRTVersion])) p
;
```

Comment: @ Vitaly Borisov : great try ..but if any key is missing its inserting null values to destination column but i want it to be empty string

Comment: I've updated answer as per requirement, but I strongly recommend to use proper types (int) instead of strings everywhere.

Comment: @ Vitaly Borisov: I was just trying to extend the same for my requirement  as  
 DeviceCurrentMISCRECrossBoundaryBURVersion instead 
 of [DeviceMIS-BURVersion] ,DeviceFutureMISCRECrossBoundaryBURVersion                                              
 instead of [FutureMIS-BURVersion] and so on as output column  . Any help on this

Comment: Just replace to AS [anyNameYouNeed] in the select statement

Comment: @ Vitaly Borisov: what if we have date format i,e: '2:21/06/2017,3:11/02/2014' Tried clicking but getting: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: You don't have enough points to vote, but you can accept the answer

Comment: @ Vitaly Borisov: Done !! Now what if I have date format i,e: '2:21/06/2017,3:11/02/2014'  or '2:21.06.2017,3:11.02.2014' instead of  '2:21,3:50'

Comment: In the function replace Cross apply to this:  CROSS APPLY OPENJSON('["' + REPLACE(j.[value],':','","') + '"]') i

Comment: Can we able to handle both string and above said date format at a time in single function?

Comment: Yes, just replace as per my previous comment

Comment: OPENJSON Used in above function is not 
 compatible in SQL 2014 But works in 2016, any alternative?

Comment: Write parser function using string functions instead of OpenJson

Answer (score 0):

The following query will parse the comma separated string `2:21,5:50,4:55,7:80,9:33` into individual component `2:21`, `5:30` etc. From there you can use similar method to extract `bb` from `aa:bb`.

Since the key-value pair is in format `aa:bb`, you can use `datepart(hour, 'aa:bb')` and `datepart(minute, 'aa:bb')` to extract `aa` and `bb`

```
; with 
Tab1 as
(
    select  val  = '2:21,5:50,4:55,7:80,9:33'
)
select  t.*, k1.k, k2.k, k3.k, k4.k, k5.k
from    Tab1 t
    cross apply
    (
        select  i = charindex(',', t.val),
            k = substring(t.val, 1, charindex(',', t.val + ',', 1) - 1)
    ) k1
    cross apply
    (
        select  i = charindex(',', t.val, k1.i + 1),
            k = substring(t.val, k1.i + 1, charindex(',', t.val + ',', k1.i + 1) - k1.i - 1)
    ) k2
    cross apply
    (
        select  i = charindex(',', t.val, k2.i + 1),
            k = substring(t.val, k2.i + 1, charindex(',', t.val + ',', k2.i + 1) - k2.i - 1)
    ) k3
    cross apply
    (
        select  i = charindex(',', t.val, k3.i + 1),
            k = substring(t.val, k3.i + 1, charindex(',', t.val + ',', k3.i + 1) - k3.i - 1)
    ) k4
    cross apply
    (
        select  i = charindex(',', t.val, k4.i + 1),
            k = substring(t.val, k4.i + 1, charindex(',', t.val + ',', k4.i + 1) - k4.i - 1)
    ) k5
```

Comment: @ Squirrel : If any key is not found in the key value pair gives unexpected o/p from your logic i,e: instead of this '2:21,5:50,4:55,7:80,9:33'  say suppose we have like this           '5:50,4:55,7:80,9:33'  then whole parsing messes up

Comment: how do you know which key is missing ?

Comment: are you saying first key is always `2`, second is always `5` ?

Comment: it need not be!! order can change as well i,e: thing is it can max contain all the keys 2,5,4,7,9 present in it '2:21,5:50,4:55,7:80,9:33' or it can '2:21,5:50,4:55' but the key will be from subset of (2,5,4,7,9). If any key is not found then corresponding column should be empty string

Comment: anyway, you can use similar method like `charindex()`, `substring()` to extract the key & value that you required

Answer (score 0):

This is a pain in SQL Server.  You can do this with recursive CTEs:

```
 with cte as (
      select convert(varchar(max), left(FutureMISBoundaryVersion, charindex(',', FutureMISBoundaryVersion) - 1)) as FutureMISBoundaryVersion,
             convert(varchar(max), left(CurrentMISBoundaryVersion, charindex(',', CurrentMISBoundaryVersion) - 1)) as CurrentMISBoundaryVersion,
             convert(varchar(max), left(FutureHAMBoundaryVersion, charindex(',', FutureHAMBoundaryVersion) - 1)) as FutureHAMBoundaryVersion,
             convert(varchar(max), left(CurrentHAMBoundaryVersion, charindex(',', FutureMISBoundaryVersion) - 1)) as CurrentHAMBoundaryVersion,
             stuff(FutureMISBoundaryVersion, 1, charindex(',', FutureMISBoundaryVersion), '') + ',' as FutureMISBoundaryVersion_rest,
             stuff(CurrentMISBoundaryVersion, 1, charindex(',', CurrentMISBoundaryVersion), '') + ',' as CurrentMISBoundaryVersion_rest,
             stuff(FutureHAMBoundaryVersion, 1, charindex(',', FutureHAMBoundaryVersion), '') + ',' as FutureHAMBoundaryVersion_rest,
             stuff(CurrentHAMBoundaryVersion, 1, charindex(',', CurrentHAMBoundaryVersion), '') + ',' as CurrentHAMBoundaryVersion_rest,
             1 as lev
      from t
      union all
      select convert(varchar(max), left(FutureMISBoundaryVersion_rest, charindex(',', FutureMISBoundaryVersion_rest) - 1)) as FutureMISBoundaryVersion,
             convert(varchar(max), left(CurrentMISBoundaryVersion_rest, charindex(',', CurrentMISBoundaryVersion_rest) - 1)) as CurrentMISBoundaryVersion,
             convert(varchar(max), left(FutureHAMBoundaryVersion_rest, charindex(',', FutureHAMBoundaryVersion_rest) - 1)) as FutureHAMBoundaryVersion,
             convert(varchar(max), left(CurrentHAMBoundaryVersion_rest, charindex(',', CurrentHAMBoundaryVersion_rest) - 1)) as CurrentHAMBoundaryVersion,
             stuff(FutureMISBoundaryVersion_rest, 1, charindex(',', FutureMISBoundaryVersion_rest), '') as FutureMISBoundaryVersion_rest,
             stuff(CurrentMISBoundaryVersion_rest, 1, charindex(',', CurrentMISBoundaryVersion_rest), '') as CurrentMISBoundaryVersion_rest,
             stuff(FutureHAMBoundaryVersion_rest, 1, charindex(',', FutureHAMBoundaryVersion_rest), '') as FutureHAMBoundaryVersion_rest,
             stuff(CurrentHAMBoundaryVersion_rest, 1, charindex(',', CurrentHAMBoundaryVersion_rest), '') as CurrentHAMBoundaryVersion_rest,
             lev + 1
      from cte
      where FutureMISBoundaryVersion_rest like '%,%'
     )
select FutureMISBoundaryVersion, CurrentMISBoundaryVersion, FutureHAMBoundaryVersion, CurrentHAMBoundaryVersion, lev
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bdad7146640c159db97f73a72b113321) is a db<>fiddle.